# what is the best way to update in asp.net core

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm watching some tutorial programming about asp.net core
In some tutorial lecturers use this code for update data in database

```
DataContext db = new DataContext();
var query = db.TblUsers.where(x => x.Id == 3).single();
query.Name = "Sami";
db.TblUsers.Attach(query);
db.Entry(query).state = EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();
```

But some lecturers use this code for updating data in database

```
DataContext db = new DataContext();
var query = db.TblUsers.where(x => x.Id == 3).single();
query.Name = "Sami";
db.Update(query);
db.SaveChanges();
```

In fact I'm confuse to use which of them? Because both code working.
Please tell me what is exactly different between those codes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your current code, there is no need to use `Attach` for the first way. If you want to update Model by retriving record from database, kindly go with second way which is much convenience.

For `Attach`, it will put entity in the graph into the Unchanged state, and set entity as `Modified` by `db.Entry(query).state = EntityState.Modified`, then the changes in `query` will be saved to database. Since `db.TblUsers.where(x => x.Id == 3).single()` is already tracking the `query`, there is no need to use `Attach`.
There are two types for query, `tracking` and `no-tracking`. If you did not specificy the query as `no-tracking` expecitly like `db.TblUsers.AsNoTracking().where(x => x.Id == 3).single()`, the entity will be tracking which is `Unchanged` state.

For `db.Update(query);`, it will begins tracking the given entity in the `EntityState.Modified` state such that it will be updated in the database when Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges is called.